# Ffmpeg - Concat two video file - Defining absolute path of video file not working

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, absolute-path

I am using Ffmpeg to concate three mp4 files.

I am following this article
[https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join,%20merge)%20media%20files](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files)

Check topic **Concat protocol**

I have 3 **.ts** files, now running following command that merges all 3 .ts files properly

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:video1.ts|video2.ts|video3.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

Now same command I want to run from php code, so I am giving absolute path of each file, and the command is as below.

```
/home/pc-16/bin/ffmpeg -i "concat:|'/var/temp/rt-web/web/video/iRec/HOKPINzHFS/video1.ts'|'/var/temp/rt-web/web/video/iRec/HOKPINzHFS/video2.ts'|'/var/temp/rt-web/web/video/iRec/HOKPINzHFS/video3.ts'" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "/var/temp/rt-web/web/video/iRec/HOKPINzHFS/final.mp4"
```

This gives following error

```
concat:|'/var/temp/rt-web/web/video/iRec/HOKPINzHFS/video1.ts'|'/var/temp/rt-web/web/video/iRec/HOKPINzHFS/video2.ts'|'/var/temp/rt-web/web/video/iRec/HOKPINzHFS/video3.ts': No such file or directory
```

Have also tried the same command by removing single quotes from file names

```
/home/pc-16/bin/ffmpeg -i "concat:|/var/temp/rt-web/web/video/iRec/HOKPINzHFS/video1.ts|/var/temp/rt-web/web/video/iRec/HOKPINzHFS/video2.ts|/var/temp/rt-web/web/video/iRec/HOKPINzHFS/video3.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "/var/temp/rt-web/web/video/iRec/HOKPINzHFS/final.mp4"
```

but got the same error message.

Can anybody tell me how to specify absolute file names in command.

Comment: Why do you start your concat by a pipe ...

Comment: /home/pc-16/bin/ffmpeg -i "concat:|'/var/blahblah .... it should be /home/pc-16/bin/ffmpeg -i "concat:'/var/blahblah ... not completely sure but you should test it !